# Why are the positions of the windows of the same application in a birdview not fixed?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments

Suppose you have opened several windows of an application, such as opened several pdf files using evince. Then the windows will cluster in the icon of the application on the left panel of the desktop. When clicking the application icon, a birdview of all the windows will be shown, and you can click any window in the birdview to restore that window and switch the current focus to that window.

But when there are more and more windows opened for an application, each window in the birdview  will be smaller and harder  to be seen clearly of what it is about, which makes selecting the desired window more difficult.

There is another thing adding to the difficulty. When you go back and forth between clicking application icon to see the birdview of multiple windows and selecting one window from the birdview, the order of the windows in the birdview will change from time to time when you click to see the birdview. If you happen to choose the wrong window from the birdview and then go back to birdview, you will be unable to choose a different window, because the ordering of the windows in the birdview has been changed and each window is so small to see its content.

1. So I was wondering how the ordering of multiple windows of an
   application in the birdview changes from time to time?
2. Can I request the developer of the Desktop of Ubuntu to fix the
   ordering of windows in the birdview, and also to find a way to make
   each window larger to see in the birdview?

My Ubuntu is 12.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

And also such problem exists with `gnome-shell`, but there is a fix for that with `Native Window Placement extension` by [Webupd8 team](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html), may it can be a clue to fix this in unity.

Comment: Thanks! What is gnome-shell used for?

Comment: You can replace `gnome-shell` with unity. Oh my god! you have six gold medals!

Comment: Am I using gnome-shell or unity? Which one do you recommend me to use? Yeah, stupid people can have many medals.

Comment: By default ubuntu comes with unity and it is really good for me (in some cases not!), and you can install gnome-shell and have a good experience too. Try to test ;)